# Synchronising threads

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, semaphore

How can I make two threads to wait for each other till they complete one loop each using pthreads?

```
void* th1Fn()
{  
    while(1)
    {
        //do something
        printf("I'm done");
        //signal that i'm done
        //wait for thread2 so that I can repeat the cycle
    }
}

void* th2Fn()
{       
    while(1)
    {
        //do something
        printf("I'm done");
        //signal that i'm done
        //wait for thread1 so that I can repeat the cycle
    }
}
```

Comment: Sling a semaphore unit back and forth between the threads - easy.  No need for anything more complex than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `pthread_barrier_wait`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_barrier_wait.html

And here is a documented example for this function: http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/threads/pthread_barrier_demo.c.html

Comment: This is close. But I want to use the barrier in loop. Do I need to declare an array or it can I use the same barrier?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? It's all clear in the doc. I would use one barriers for each synchronization point.

Comment: You can use the same barrier multiple times.